# Confusion on dealloc calls

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, dealloc

I have a basic question here.

I know that dealloc will be called when the object's reference count becomes zero,and dealloc releases all the resources hold by the object or frees memory, right?

The object reference count becomes zero if we send release message to that object right?.

Lets consider the following object with its property created as,

```
@property (retain) NSString* myString;//reference count 1
```

and dealloc

```
[myString release];//reference count 0
[super dealloc];
```

I am not releasing the `myString` object any where except in dealloc.

My question is who is making `myString` object reference count to zero so that dealloc will be called?

Please clarify my doubt.

Comment: Use ARC, that eliminates retain/release/autorelease and dealloc.

Comment: @Zaph: ARC doesn't eliminate `dealloc`; it makes it a lot less likely that you'll need to override it, but there are still cases where you would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything that maintains ownership of the object is responsible for releasing it. For example if the code you posted is the only thing that maintains ownership of the `NSString` stored in `myString` then when you call release the reference count will be decreased and the object will likely be deallocated (String literals are different). Now if you passed `myString` around or something else requested `myString` and retains it then that code is also responsible for releasing it which may be before or after you release it in the dealloc method.

I recommend referring to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html) for reinforcing this concept.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your property myString is within your class MyClass. Each instance of your class is created and (presumably!) released. When that instance is [released], your dealloc method of MyClass is called. Your dealloc in turn calls release on your properties, which in turn invokes their dealloc, and so on until you reach the 'bottom' of this stack of objects using objects.

Comment: `release` does not necessarily result in `dealloc`. *The last* `release` will; a `release` that balances out a previous `retain` will not.

Answer (score 0):

Your object will only be free'ed if the retain/release pairs match up. If you follow the cocoa memory management (see apple docs - advances memory management programming guide) 
rules, you are the only 'owner' at that point - and running dealloc zap's the last reference away - free'ing the object.

Comment: `dealloc` doesn't “zap the last reference away”; releasing the last reference causes `dealloc` to be called.

Comment: yup - dealloc runs (last ref to the obj with NSString inside gone) - calls release on the NSString object (zap) which at that point should have no ref ...

Comment: Ah, so you mean “zap's the last reference” *to the string*. A vital detail.